# Жизнь и удивительные приключения сообщений об ошибках

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, faq, мета

Хочу поделиться с вами соображениями о том, как можно обрабатывать сообщения об ошибках (дефектах, багах), как организовать работу с ними и что означают специальные метки `[статус-*]`.

Схема примерно отражает опыт работы последнего месяца, в течение которого были разобраны и классифицированы все имеющися на Мете вопросы с меткой [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82). В процессе пара десятков дефектов, относящихся к локализации, были исправлены. Ещё восемь дефектов были переданы разработчикам; один из них сегодня исправили.

```
Участник создаёт на Мете сообщение с меткой 
дефект
  |
  ↓
Это вообще дефект?
  |
  |→ нет, так и должно быть: статус-так-задумано или замена метки на предложение.
  |
  |←→ непонятно: статус-проверка
  |
  да, похоже на дефект.
  ↓
Получается ли его воспроизвести?
  |
  |→ нет. статус-не-воспроизводится
  |                             |
  да                            |
  ↓                             ↓
```

```
статус-воспроизведено ←———— Автор объяснил, как воспроизвести
  |
  ↓
Дефект можно исправить силами модераторов и/или других участников?
  |
  |→ нет: добавляем метку
  | статус-отложено 
  |  |  (потому что сделали всё от нас зависящее),
  |  |  передаём разработчикам,
  |  |  можем завести багрепорт на Meta SE.
  |  |
  да |
  ↓  |
На это нужно много времени, 
необходимо подумать или посоветоваться?
  |  |
```

```
  |———→ да: уходит в условный бэклог* сообщества.
  |  |  При начале активной работы над дефектом добавляем 
  |  | статус-запланировано, 
  |  |  |  предлагаем варианты перевода,
  |  |  |  обсуждаем и т.п.
  |  |  |
 нет |  |
  ↓  |  |
Правим|
  |  |  |
  ↓  ↓  ↓
статус-завершено.
```

Пришлось добавить разрывы, иначе схему не было видно целиком.

<sub>* [Бэклог](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum#.D0.91.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.B0) — список всех задач, которые будут выполнены когда-нибудь, но не в ближайший рабочий период</sub>

Comment: Идея отличная! Мне не до конца понятно, как организовать процесс на стадии [meta-tag:запланировано]. Далеко не все дефекты получают достаточно внимания со стороны разработчиков. Сказать, что все добавленные в базу дефектов проблемы запланированы, на мой взгляд, не корректно. Возможно стоит использовать [meta-tag:статус-воспроизведено] до тех пор пока не будет ясно, что кто-то действительно взялся за дело?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: я хотел бы какой-то меткой обозначать, что проблема не решается силами сообщества и передана дальше. То есть мы о ней знаем, совершили необходимые действия и теперь не должны ничего делать, а только ждать. Иная ситуация — когда её только воспроизвели, но ещё никуда не сообщили. Каким другим способом можно это обозначить или какую метку использовать?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: что если использовать [meta-tag:статус-отложено]?

Comment: Хороший выход из ситуации.

Comment: На десктопе и мобильном браузере всё выглядит по-разному :(

Answer (score 12):

И небольшая сводка по результатам работы сообщества за 10 месяцев в формате Stack Overflow:

Сообщения с меткой [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) (216 вопросов) и статусом:

- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be): [134](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82).

  - В том числе [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f): [105](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).
- [статус-воспроизведено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be): [46](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

  - В том числе [статус-запланировано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be): [5](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)
  - В том числе [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f): [25](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)
- [статус-не-воспроизводится](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f): [8](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)
- [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be): [25](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)
- [статус-проверка](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0): [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82).
- [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be): [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82+%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

Что меня радует в этой статистике:

- Довольно много дефектов исправлено. Из них 80% касались локализации, с этими было одновременно проще и сложнее всего.
- Что эта статистика вообще есть и баги классифицированы. Теперь я могу спокойно спать по ночам. :)

Что меня беспокоит:

- У нас тут довольно много «подвисших» багов. Непонятно, занимается ли ими кто-то.
- Есть ряд «сложных ситуаций» с локализацией. Мы вроде бы знаем, что сейчас — плохо. Но когда и кто будет думать над улучшением — неизвестно.
- Объявленных дефектов (а также и предложений) достаточно много. Непонятно, каковы приоритеты, чем нужно заниматься в первую очередь.

Предлагаю подумать, как организовать работу, чтобы всё-таки добраться и исправить их.

Comment: В список их!​​​​

Comment: @Qwertiy: какой список? )

Comment: @Qwertiy, под цифрами количеств — ссылки. по ссылкам — списки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, речь про _"У нас тут довольно много «подвисших» багов."_ В отдельный список :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я так понимаю, что это `статус-воспроизведено`, в данный момент — 46 штук (ссылка под цифрой).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати, математика не сходится. с меткой дефект — **216**, а по отдельным категориям: 134+46+8+25+1= **214**. // нашлись! это [`статус-отклонено`](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82+%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). добавил их в ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, на то я и развешивал метки, чтобы сразу находить потерянные баги. :)