# Судьба предложений, реализация которых находится вне рамок компетенции местных модераторов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Допустим, какой-нибудь участник сделал заплюсованное сообществом предложение,  — [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2830/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5?cb=1), — но реализация находится вне рамок компетенции местных модераторов. Вопрос: что становится с хорошими предложениями, — их доносят до тех, кого следует? Ведь мы здесь не «разводим флуд ради флуда», а желаем реальной помощи сайту.

Comment: Тоже интересно)) А то как-будто просто душу отвел) Хотя, может быть есть гораздо правильно место для размещения предложений. 
Честно говоря,  в итоге, по результатам каких-либо обсуждений и решений - хотелось бы даже на своем вопросе видеть какую-то большую блямбу с надписью: "Была одобрена" или "К сожалению отклонено из-за..." и т.д..с уведомлением в сообщениях....
.....Ждем-с ответ

Comment: пример не очень удачный: проблема и решение спорные.

Comment: @jfs, сейчас согласен. Но когда я писал создавал этот тред, у примера было, ЕМНИП, 7 плюсов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11):

В общем случае с предложениями на уровне движка ничего не происходит. Чуть выше шанс, что вам ответят, на MSE — месте, где и принято обсуждать общедвижковые предложения и баги. И то с большой вероятностью выше предложение (и даже баг) проигнорируют, даже если ваш пост наберёт уйму плюсов, или закроют с отметкой "баян", что более вероятно. Многие предложения висят на MSE годами.

У разработчиков свои приоритеты, не отвлекайте их своими глупостями. :)

Предложения, на которые обращают внимание на локальных Метах:

1. Предложения, которые вписываются в рамки движка: работа с метками, постами, справкой и т. п. Они будут выполнены высокореповыми пользователями, модераторами, локальной администрацией — теми, кто имеет возможность выполнить принятое сообществом решение.
2. Предложения по актуальным проблемам, например, по локализации. Если какая-то строка в интерфейсе не переведена, то это будет исправлено пользователями, имеющими доступ в Transifex. Если строка недоступна для перевода, то эта информация будет доведена до разработчиков администрацией. То исключение, когда связь прямая и достаточно быстрая.
3. Общесайтовые предложения, которые обсуждаются долгие месяцы (или годы) вместе с администрацией и другими пользователями. Например, появился шанс, что будут реализованы перекрёстные ссылки. Это было предложение одного из пользователей, его подхватила администрация, и идея оказалась в тренде раскручивания локализованных сайтов.

Писать о чём-то другом — пустая трата времени. Лучше сразу на MSE, там пошлют быстрее. :)

Comment: Как обычно везде: участвуйте в жизни общества/компании/проекта, предлагайте, не будьте безучастны. А как только начинаешь, всегда выясняется, что всем по *** =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: несмотря на согласие с фактической стороной в ответе, мне кажется тон ответа слишком негативный. В качестве анекдота, те (немногие) баги (в основном с ios-app), которые я сам на MSE публиковал, исправлялись в течение дня. Хотя [какие-то вещи могут и годами висеть](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/137096). На глаз [~10% всех предложений завершены](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). На практически [все популярные предложения есть реакция](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Comment: @jfs Ох, сначала "anecdote" переводят как "анекдот", теперь уже "анекдот" оброс новым значением... Хотя чо, все певцы ртом уже "артисты"...

Comment: @Discord: я вас не понял, какую мысль вы хотели донести? Снова по-видимому фактически правильный у вас комментарий (я не знаю используется ли в русском слово "анекдот", известное минимум с 18 века, в значении "anecdotal evidence"), но негативный по тону. Можно его заметно улучшить, если вы поняли что я пытался выразить и предложить более удачный русский перевод.

Answer (score 9):

Компания одна. Понятия «местных модераторов» не существует. Все предложения по реализации публикуемые на (любой) Мете попадает на доску запросов сообщества/дефектов. Далее, над ними работают ответственные сотрудники. Процесс един для всех сообществ сети [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/).

Что может быть исправлено крайне быстро:

- Небольшие дефекты движка.
- Любые критические дефекты движка.
- Дефекты вызванные локализацией.
- Все, что касается локализации.

В этих случаях, я обращаю внимание разработчиков на проблему в обход процессам компании, что могу делаю сам. Это позволяет действительно эффективно исправлять дефекты.

Реализация нового функционала требует длительной оценки – кодовая база единая для всех сайтов. Кому–то нравится, что картинки открываются в новом окне, а кому–то нет. Все–таки сайтами сети пользуются много десятков миллионов человек. Мы стараемся подходить к функционалу обдумано.

Одним из выходов из ситуации может быть использование [предложенного @Nick Volynkin процесса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2441/). Надеюсь, в будущем получится придерживаться его правилам.

---

П. С. Спасибо за ваши отзывы! Все пожелания и предложения рассматриваются ответственными за это сотрудниками, но чтобы обдумать их требуется время.